# Execute directive/function only once ionic2

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have a directive which is passed in an ion-list like this:

```
<ion-item-sliding [animateItemSliding]="shouldAnimate" </ion-item>
```

Basicly it is a custom directive that just applies a css rule of transform animation which acts like sliding, and reverse back to normal state.
I am exicuting it via setting the shouldAnimate boolean like

```
export class PageName {

shouldAnimate: boolean; ... }

ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.shouldAnimate = true;
};

ionViewWillLeave() {  
    this.shouldAnimate = false;
};
```

This works for a moment by using the Lifecycle events. But, if the page is generated again, it still sets the shouldAnimate to true.

I want to be able to find way of exicuting the directive only and **only first time** you open this page.
So, the boolean of this variable should be true only first time you open this page, and than remember this choice ( set boolean to false ) and never execute it again (or probably until you close the app and load completely again from the phone)

Answer (score 0):

It cannot be done the way you want it. Once the component is destroyed and created again, there is no way for it know that it has been created before. You need to persist the state across component's different instances somewhere. The Angular's way to do this is **a service**.

Create a service where you'll store this data.

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  shouldAnimate = false
}
```

Provide it somewhere, for example in your `AppModule`. Add this in the metadata (the object you pass to `@NgModel`).

```
providers: [MyService],
```

Now inject a singleton of this service in the component.

```
export class PageName {
  constructor(private myService: MyService) {}
}
```

Now just flip the variable once, if not already flipped. This is best done in the `OnInit` lifecycle hook.

```
ngOnInit() {
  if (!this.myService.shouldAnimate) {
    this.myService.shouldAnimate = true
  }
}
```

Your `PageName` component now might destroyed counrless times, but the service will live on, which means the data you want will persist across component's creation and destruction.

Comment: I will try this thanks, but i need the shouldAnimate to set it to false, once it is true the first time, otherwise it will run the directive each time. Just to be 100% sure you got my point, of actually doing the directive once only and never again on this page load.

Comment: Well, just set it to `false` instead of `true`... Also you cannot "do" a directive once. You can set a variable once and use it not to trigger something inside the directive. But the directive will be created by Angular if it's in the template.

Comment: Yes, sorry for my wrong expression, but I meant exactly that. Because this directive is fired up only if the boolean variable name is true. So , it all depends on that boolean.

Comment: That's exactly what this answer gives you.

Comment: I tried this, but its not working. It works only if i do this: [animateItemSliding]="myService.shouldAnimate" but it keeps showing up on each page load. If i put just [animateItemSliding]="shouldAnimate" nothing happens.

Comment: Create a reproduction.

Comment: Sorry, not sure what do you mean.